# mysql: Cpanel Database connection php_network_getaddresses error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-connection

I am facing database connection error in Cpanel hosting with below code;

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "helloDB";
$password = "MY_PASS";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Error Log...

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Comment: proper syntax of mysqli_connect 
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
`

Comment: thanks for comment.. so, whats idea about that;  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp